# Getting different results using flatMap and compactMap

Tags: swift, flatmap

I have Array A of objects of type struct

```
struct Caste {
    var arr = [1,2]
}

let siri =  [Caste(), Caste(), Caste()]
```

Now I want a single array in which all elements of each objects array consist as shown below:

```
let re1 = siri.compactMap { $0.arr }
print("COMPACT: \(re1)")
let re2 = siri.flatMap { $0.arr }
print("FLAT: \(re2)")
```

**Result:**

`COMPACT: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
 FLAT: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`

As flatMap is deprecated in Swift 4.1 I tried with compactMap but it is giving array of array not a single array.

How can I achieve via compactMap as I'm getting via flatMap.

Comment: That usage case of `flatmap` is not deprecated

Comment: One thing that the other answer doesn't cover very clearly. In the snippet `siri.compactMap { $0.arr }`, since the closure is expected to be of type `(T) -> T?`, and since Swift implicitly promote a value t of type `T` into an optional of type `T?`, what is actually returned is `Optional($0.arr)`

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` was split up into itself and `compactMap`. `flatMap` is to flatten an array while the purpose of `compactMap` is to take an array of `[T?]` and remove all nil objects making an array of `[T]`. This has a count of <= the original count depending on the number of nils.

Comment: To be more precise, there's a distinction to be made between `Any` (a protocol type) and `T` (a placeholder for a specific type)